# Can a one-line bar chart be created with Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

The goal is to create a simple one-line chart with markers at the proportional position of the values. As in the linked image example that follows with the values 0, 15, 35, 55, 82, 100, the chart should display a vertical line or small symbol with the values below the line.

[One Line Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxLrk.jpg)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight your data. Click Insert and choose a stacked bar chart. Then, if it's not what you are expecting, you can right-click the bar and choose Change Series Chart Type. In the Bar section, you should two options. Choose the second option. Through formatting, you should be able to change the colors as you need to.
[image: Stacked Bar Chart Option]